# Does static imported class loads different from non static import

Tags: java

Static import gives direct benefit of not using the class name and access the static fields directly like

```
import static java. Lang. System;
```

will allow us to use `out.println` directly instead of `System.out.println`. Does the loading of such classes like the ones I define manually be different from loading of non static import of same classes?

Comment: The other questions may look similar but they do not have any answer to say about loading of static import. I am asking from perspective of class loaders.

Comment: Statics are loaded eagerly but not sure about static import of a non static class.